# Responsive full-width tiled images

Tags: html, css

I have a full width div (`#instagram`) that has an a unordered list of images in it (the number of lis vary). I want the `ul` (and it's children) to be centered inside of the div and expand out in both directions without wrapping to next line. I have included a diagram below. How do I implement this in a responsive fashion?

```
<div id = "instagram">
  <ul class="photos">
      <li><img src = "http://placehold.it/200" /></li>
    <li><img src = "http://placehold.it/200" /></li>
    <li><img src = "http://placehold.it/200" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

**Update:** I realize that my diagram looks somewhat like a carousel but this is not what I'm looking for. I do not need any "paging" functionality. Also, I want the images to be cut off on the edges as I have shown.

**Update #2** Here is a starting jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MULCU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an extra wrapper you can centre the images ***and* crop off the excess either side**:

```
#instagram {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:blue;
    padding:20px 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#instagram .bounds {
    width:2000%;
    padding-left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
#instagram ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:-100%;
    background-color:green;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}
#instagram ul li {
    display:inline-block; 
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
}
```

**See my [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MULCU/2/)**

Comment: This works great, w/ one undesirable side effect. There is a slight bit of whitespace in between each `li` (even with removing your margin on the `li`).

Comment: That's because the `display:inline-block` you can add `margin-left:-4px` to fix it or don't make spaces in html between the elements make it like `<li></li><li></li>`

Comment: I'm okay w/ the negative left margin! Thanks

Comment: That 4px space is actually white-space. You can remove it by having no new lines or whitespace between the elements in your markup. [This article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) has loads of useful info and fixes for this.

Comment: Another way to get rid of the space is to set the font size of the container to 0. But this causes all sorts of trouble if you're using ems instead of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the white-space:nowrap property and this is what I got. I capped the max width of the whole thing so you have to fiddle with the screen size to see the "responsiveness".

```
#instagram {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    padding:10px 0;
    max-width:400px;
}

.photos {
    background-color:orange;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px 0;
    position:relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.photos li {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

c

```
<div id = "instagram">
    <ul class = "photos">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m77mt/)

Comment: This somewhat works but the first image is always fully visible since everything is aligned to the left. I want the images to start from the center and expand left and right (if the left image is partially cut off, so should the right)

Comment: Well if the instagram was a fixed width it'd be simple, you'd just push the whole list to the left with margins and relative positioning. I'm not sure if it can be done responsively without using javascript.

Comment: That's the same issue I was running into. I *really* don't want to use JS if I don't have to :/ - http://jsfiddle.net/MULCU/15/

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using divs instead of a ul it will make the solution better and easier.
consider the code below. This defines the #instagram div with fixed pixels (but it would change to be %) and bases everything else off of that. This makes the solution responsive.

I've also put the code on this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cB7e4/

```
<div id = "instagram">
  <div class="photos">
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
    <div class="images"><img src = "http://stylebizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/cascading-style-sheets-css-logo.png?0d9bf2" /></div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
#instagram
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #3AD7FF;
    position: absolute;
}

.photos
{
    width: 98%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    background: #B8FCCD;
    padding: 0% 1%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.images
{
    margin: 1.5% 1% 1% 0%;
    height: 80%;
    background: #F2FEE2;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.images img
{
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

how about sth like this?

```
.photos
    {
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    .photos li {
        float: left;
        margin:0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
```

li elements float to left and there's a small margin between the pictures

Comment: This doesn't center align the `lis`, nore does it solve the no-wrapping issue.